# CakePHP Retrieving data from custom model

Tags: cakephp

I got few models with custom queries, just don't want to fight with them so I used `$this->query` method to query DB.

Now got question...

The only way I can access data is using `$model[0][0]['field']`, is there any other way to display them in `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing your queries, follow the CakePHP naming conventions - this makes the returned data much easier to handle.

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` as Post, `comments` as `Comment` ...
```

Then you get data returned that looks very similar to what you would get from a `find()`, i.e. `$queryResults['ModelName']['FieldName]` or `$queryResults[0]['ModelName']['FieldName]`.

This link might help too. It relates to use of `find` rather than `query`, but it shows how you can create a method in your `AppModel` to automatically reformat returned data (moving computed data into a model, to avoid having returned values at [0][0]).

http://teknoid.wordpress.com/2008/09/29/dealing-with-calculated-fields-in-cakephps-find/

Comment: Thanks Roy, the link you gave me made things cleaner for me!

Answer (score 0):

avoid using query function if you can. `$this->Model->find()` makes thing makes things cleaner.